# Can not remove the modifier of final class

Tags: junit

I want to remove final key word of 1 class. I'm writting Junit for this class and I call spy of Mockito to mock a method to return an expect values to cover all cases.

After using:

```
CtClass ctClazz = ClassPool.getDefault().get(Livre.class.getName());
ctClazz.setModifiers(ctClazz.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
ctClazz.writeFile();
```

The modifier of this class is 17 but I think it should be 1 (public).

And I got the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class mediatheque.document.Livre
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.signedsupport.SignedSupportingClassProxyFactory.createProxy(SignedSupportingClassProxyFactory.java:147)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:40)
    at org.easymock.classextension.internal.MocksClassControl.createMock(MocksClassControl.java:43)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doMock(PowerMock.java:2076)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createMock(PowerMock.java:79)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createPartialMock(PowerMock.java:765)
    at test.mediatheque.document.TestDocument.testRestituer_With_Exception3(TestDocument.java:379)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$2.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:217)
    ... 19 more
```

This final class extends from an abstract class.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend (subclass) a `final` class. If you really need to do so (whether for testing or because you really need to override a method in someone else's library), you'll have to 'fork' the class. Copy its contents into a new class (updating package declaration and class references), and remove the `final` designation *there*. Then, you can extend it to your heart's content. I've used this approach quite effectively recently with respect to Spring Security.

Comment: I mean this class extends from an abstract class. It's a subclass. It is not extended by any class.

Comment: I understand, but Junit is effectively extending it (by proxy, if I recall correctly), which is why the exception is thrown. Copy ('fork') the class, point your calls to the forked version, and your test run properly.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? sorry but I did not understand you much

Comment: Hi, Now I understood. You meant I should copy this class to another class and remove final modifier and write test cases for new class? The logic of class is still kept?